# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: algorithmic

I am using TEXMAKER. Here is a code segment.

```
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
begin{algorithmic}
\FOR {$i\gets0$ to $n$} \do
    \FOR {$j \gets$0 \TO $min(i,k)$} \do 
        \IF {$j=0$ \OR $j=i$}
            \STATE $C[i,j] \gets  1$
        \ELSE
            \STATE $C[i,j] \gets  C[i-1,j-1]+C[i-1,j]$
        \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\RETURN C[n,k]

\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `\do`s, and this works fine. As a side note, use `$\min(i,k)$` instead of `$min(i,k)$`, and (as egreg mentioned in a comment) there is a pair of `$` missing from the last line of the algorithm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR {$i\gets0$ to $n$} 
    \FOR {$j \gets$0 \TO $\min(i,k)$} 
        \IF {$j=0$ \OR $j=i$}
            \STATE $C[i,j] \gets  1$
        \ELSE
            \STATE $C[i,j] \gets  C[i-1,j-1]+C[i-1,j]$
        \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\RETURN $C[n,k]$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing two `$` signs in the last line.

Comment: @egreg Indeed I am, didn't notice that one. Thanks!